# Как замокать инициализацию глобальной переменной?

Tags: python, юнит-тесты

Нужно создать мок для глобальной переменной в скрипте.

Переменная инициализируется функцией которая кидает исключение без должного окружения.

Один раз замокать я смог, но в последующих тест кейсах создается впечатление что используется мок который был пропатчен первым.

Собственно скрипт:
service/entity/list/src/handler.py

```py
from util.table import get_table

table = get_table('TABLE')

def query_db(event):
    query_args = create_query_params(event)
    query_res = table.query(**query_args)
    return query_res
```

Функция которую нужно замокать:
util/table.py

```py
def get_table(table_name):
    return get_db().table(table_name)
```

Что я пробовал:

1. Патчить функцию в месте использования

```py
class TestListEntities(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.event = MagicMock(name='event mock')
        self.table = MagicMock(name='table mock')
        self.query = MagicMock(name='query mock')
        self.query_result = {'items': []}
        self.table.query.return_value = self.query_result

    def test_empty(self):
        with patch('service.entity.list.src.handler.get_table', return_value=self.table):
            from service.entity.list.src.handler import query_db
            response = query_db(self.event)

            self.assertTrue(self.table.query.called)
```

это вызывает реальную функцию, которая кидает исключение

2. Патчить функцию в месте обьявления

```py
    def test_empty(self):
        with patch('util.table.get_table', return_value=self.table):
            from service.entity.list.src.handler import query_db
            response = query_db(self.event)
            self.assertTrue(self.table.query.called)
```

Работает как ожидается, **НО** в последующих тестах используется этот же мок.

**Итого** нужно пропатчить функцию которая инициализирует глобальную переменную. Получилось сделать это только для одного тест кейса, но для нескольких используется всегда один и тот же мок.

Comment: Та же проблема! Есть у кого рекомендации?

Comment: А запуск интерпритатора на каждый тест решит же пооблему?

Comment: @StrangerintheQ да, но нужно чтобы за один запуск проходили все тесты

Comment: @Dmitry ну тогда у меня для Вас,  предположительно, плохие новоти:)